# jQuery hover and out function for each

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover

I am very bad at writing scripts. This is what I have written and it's giving an error. I like to add an hover and hoverout function for every div with class `swiper-slide` and in that function I like to target the element with class `img-responsive'.

To do so here is what I have written so far:

```
var displayImg = "";
$('#FeaturedBanner .swiper-slide').hover(

    function () {
      displayImg = $(this).find('img-responsive');
      // Some function for var displayImg 
    },
    function () {
      displayImg = $(this).find('img-responsive');
      // Some Alternate function for var displayImg 
    }
);
```

The problem is with assigning element to var `displayImg`. Since I like to target the element with class `img-responsive` within `swiper-slide` in both functions. I don't know any better way and I'm hoping to learn a better way to do it.

Comment: can you add more info? For instance, html fragment or js framework you are using....

Comment: What is your problem/issue?

Comment: Can be closed under the official close reason: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error._

Answer (score -2):

Sorry, I found the issue in my code, I forgot to add the dot before the class.